# Current rating of center-tapped full wave rectifier vs full wave bridge rectifier

Tags: transformer, rectifier

I was going through the Art of Electronics (Horowitz & Hill) and in the section on center-tapped full wave rectifiers (pg.47) it says:

> "The output voltage is half what you get if you use a bridge
>   rectifier. It is not the most efficient circuit in terms of
>   transformer design, because each half of the secondary is used only
>   half the time. Thus the current through the winding during that time
>   is twice what it would be for a true full-wave circuit. Heating in the
>   windings, calculated from Ohm's law, is I^2R, so you have four times
>   the heating half the time, or twice the average heating of an
>   **equivalent full-wave bridge circuit**. **You would have to choose a transformer with a current rating 1.4 (square root of 2) times as
>   large, as compared with the (better) bridge circuit**; besides costing
>   more, the resulting supply would be bulkier and heavier. "

Why would the current rating be ~1.4 times more than the bridge circuit?
Also, 'Equivalent full-wave bridge circuit' refers to one with the same output characteristics as the center-tapped circuit right?

Comment: Keeping reading Art of Elec. it's good medicine for an EE student.  There's a lab workbook that can also teach you a lot.  Makes you build stuff rather than just reading about it.

Comment: I believe I do have access to the lab workbook so I'll start using it. Thanks! I've been told that I should only read the analog portions of the book though, as the digital parts are outdated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, at a current \$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\$ lower your \$I^2R\$ heating will be half, so the overall copper heating would be the same as with the bridge.

Win Hill et al. are simplifying things a bit here by ignoring the diode drops. In the case of a requirement to get a very low voltage where the diode drops make significant difference, and/or if the granularity of the lamination size selection leads to a transformer that has more capability than required, the centre-tapped configuration may make a lot of sense.

Also, not all the transformer losses are copper losses, so doubling copper losses does not increase the total transformer losses by 2:1, especially with cheap lams.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm going off topic here, but how much would lamination size affect the capability of the transformer? Would it not be a minor difference?

Comment: @Ammar For bespoke transformers, each standard lamination step is something like 30% in watts but you can stack the laminations thicker or thinner if you don't care about filling a bobbin. Here are the steps in off-the-shelf transformers from Tamura (3FD series): 1.1 2.4 6 12 - as you can see they tend to go up in steps of ~2:1 in watts, so a factor of 1.4 is less than the step.